# Access Group Request

Tags: permissions

i want to send more than one request to multiple SharePoint group in the same time ?

or send one request to multiple SharePoint group by code ?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you please try to add more details to your question regarding what you try to do? Right now the question is a bit difficult to grasp I'm afraid.

Comment: i make registration page in SharePoint and i want the user send request to access multiple group
there page named access denied i used it to send one request by i cant use it to send more than one at the same time

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what you are trying to say :/

Comment: http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/12/09/how-to-configure-the-site-access-request-in-sharepoint-2013/
i use this link to send request to group in share point but this send request to the site i want send request to specific group  not all the site